# Creating a polygon by joining polylines in Google maps

Tags: polygon

We are trying to create boundary maps of various zones in a city using Google maps or earth. Creating polygons for each zone makes the common boundary look different with zoom. Hence we are planning to create segments (shared boundary) with polylines. However, this requires joining multiple polylines (boundary segments) to create a zone (closed boundary) with properties of a polygon. I could not get any option where we can do this. Can anyone help us to address this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into these links, it can be of help
Example:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/drawing/drawing-tools.html

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#drawing_tools